# Run Batch file with Git Commands in ASP.Net Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, git, batch-file

I have created a batch file using web application to commit and push my Files into Git Repository which is as follows:

```bat
git status
git pull
git add file.properties file.yaml file_metric.yaml
git commit -m Test Message
git push
```

I am calling this batch file with a button click in Web Application.

My Code is as follows:

```c#
//** File is created, now call the Batch file.
                    // Get the full file path

                    string strFilePath = sPathName;
                    // Create the ProcessInfo object
                    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
                    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
                    psi.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(strFilePath);
                    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                    psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                    psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
                    psi.WorkingDirectory = logFolderPath;

                    // Start the process
                    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);

                    // Open the batch file for reading
                    System.IO.StreamReader strm = System.IO.File.OpenText(strFilePath);

                    // Attach the output for reading
                    System.IO.StreamReader sOut = proc.StandardOutput;

                    // Attach the in for writing
                    System.IO.StreamWriter sIn = proc.StandardInput;

                    // Write each line of the batch file to standard input
                    while (strm.Peek() != -1)
                    {
                        sIn.WriteLine(strm.ReadLine());
                    }

                    strm.Close();

                    // Exit CMD.EXE
                    string stEchoFmt = "# {0} run successfully. Exiting";


                    sIn.WriteLine(String.Format(stEchoFmt, strFilePath));
                    //sIn.WriteLine("EXIT");


                    // Close the process
                    proc.Close();


                    // Read the sOut to a string.
                    string results = sOut.ReadToEnd().Trim();



                    // Close the io Streams;
                    sIn.Close(); 
                    sOut.Close();
```

I receive the results, however, the results are not complete and the files are not committed or Pushed into the Repository.

The output which I get is as follows:

```cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600] (c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation.
All rights reserved.

folderPath\Test>git status On branch master Your branch is up to date
with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   file.properties     new file:   file.yaml   new file:  
file_metric.yaml

Changes not staged for commit:   (use "git add <file>..." to update
what will be committed)   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard
changes in working directory)

    modified:   Git5.bat

Untracked files:   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be
committed)

    Git_Bat.Bat     ../TestGit_Bat.Bat


folderPath\Test>git pull
Already up to date.

folderPath\Test>git add file.properties file.yaml file_metric.yaml

folderPath\Test>git commit -m YAML Files

folderPath\Test>git push

folderPath\Test># folderPath\Test/Git_Bat.Bat run successfully.
Exiting

folderPath\Test>
```

It can be seen that I get no output after the **`Git.add Files Command`**.

When I try to run the above batch File *directly using the Terminal, it runs successfully, and the files are pushed correctly.*

Are there any changes required when calling through the Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my Mistake and would like to correct it Myself...

The Error was while creating the Batch file, the file names and comments were not enclosed in double quotes. It should be as follows:

```
git status
git pull
git add "file.properties" "file.yaml" "file_metric.yaml"
git commit -m "Test Message"
git push
```

Hope this helps anyone else.
Happy Coding :)